# Rad Combo Box Control's DataTextField and DataValueField

Tags: asp.net

I have used a webservice to populate a Rad Combo Box, when the page is loaded, I need the ability to display the DataTextField, based on the returned DataValueField item

Answer (score 0):

For computations on the bound data, you either need to invoke the web service manually and programmably create the list via:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combo_clientsidebasics.html

Or when bound via web service, you can loop through after the fact, hook up an event handler to OnClientItemDataBound (to process one at a time) or OnClientItemsRequested (or to loop through all in bulk).

HTH.